# Which is a good way to prevent data to be stealth through cookie?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies

Is this alright? I'm trying to check if this is enough to prevent bad information (special characters) to be passed through text input.

```
function setCookie() 
{
var x = "sessionID=fmpinho";
document.cookie = x+"; secure"; 
}

function stopRKey(evt) 
{
    var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
    var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
    if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text")) {return false;}
}

function changeTxt(inputVar) 
{
    var inputVar = document.getElementById("uEntry").value;
    inputVar = inputVar.replace(/\<|\>|\"|\'|\%|\;|\(|\)|\&|\+|\-/g,""); 
    document.write("<h1>Hello " + inputVar + "!</h1><p id=\"enjoyPara2\">Please enjoy the Web site!</p>");
}
```

Comment: you mean like protecting against a malicious attacker who tries to add javaScript to your cookie?

Comment: What are you trying to protect here? What prevents an attacker from editing their own cookie using their own browser? Replacing "special characters" in JavaScript is not sufficient to prevent XSS because any attacker will bypass the JavaScript - however I'm not sure exactly what you're doing here so can't comment further.

Answer (score 0):

With a good amount of trepidation, I would say that that is a fairly effective Javascript XSS filter, so long as this is the *only* place where you are using the value of `inputVar`. There does not seem to be any bypasses [easily accessible](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet), although that does not mean that none exist.